# Failed to update the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild binaries

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube- Version 5.1.1 - LGPL V3

Jenkins- ver. 1.651.3

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error Logs-

```
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Checking for updates...
Could not connect to the SonarQube server. Check the url is correct and that the server is available. Url: http://abcd-ef-ghijkl.mnop-qrst.com
Failed to update the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild binaries. Check the server url, verify that the C# plugin is correctly installed on the SonarQube server and that the SonarQube server has been restarted.
Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Comment: From the error it is evident that the SonarQube Scanner is not able to connect to the SonarQube server, verify your SonarQube Server settings whether they are correct or not.

Comment: Thanks @Suresh .. There was no n/w available so was the error.